# How can I test a class that is not a module in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a file `MyClass.js` that I needed to load synchronously in my HTML so I removed the `export` code because loading a module using the `<script>` with the `type="module"` attribute is async. This solved the problem that I had with being able to use the class the way I needed to in my app.

The problem now is that I can't import the class in my Jest test suite since I was originally importing it as a module, and it no longer is a module. It seems that no matter what I do `MyClass` always ends up being `undefined`. I've verified the path to the file is correct.

What I've tried:

- Load the code and parse it with eval(). I'm not sure why this doesn't work:

  ```
  const myClassCode = fs.readFileSync('./js/myClass.js', 'utf-8');
  eval(myClassCode);
  ```
- Basic import or require statements. I believe these both require the MyClass.js to be a module.
- Extract the code in a sandbox and then pull the class back into the test:

  ```
  const classFileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../MyClass.js'), 'utf-8');

  // Create a new context with a global object.
  const context = {
    MyClass: undefined,
  };
  vm.createContext(context);

  // Run the class file content in the created context.
  vm.runInContext(classFileContent, context);

  // Get the class from the context.
  const MyClass= context.MyClass;
  ```

I imagine that this must be a somewhat common task that should be trivial but I just don't see the easy solution to importing this class into my test. Changing the MyClass.js back into a module is not an option as that would break my actual app. I'm pretty new to js so I'm guessing I am overlooking something here. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems that between the options of fixing your app or hacking the test harness, you're choosing the later.

Comment: @Ouroborus I played around, for literally hours, trying to load the module in my app but in the end I need this class to load and parse first. The only way I could guarantee this was to load the class synchronously, which is impossible with a module. So this is where I am now. I'd rather have a hacked test than unreliable code in the application.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning!!! I advise against using this technique in production code, eval() can expose your application to serious security risks if used incorrectly.** Almost every time eval() is the wrong way to accomplish your task. In my case I am using it for testing, **You have been warned!**

---

I was able to solve the problem using `eval()` but I had to make some changes.

It seems that `eval()` creates the class within it's own scope but the class remains out of scope in the script that calls `eval()`. To fix this we need to set an assignment to `MyClass` in the the `eval()`.

Instead of:

```
const myClassCode = fs.readFileSync('./js/myClass.js', 'utf-8');
eval(myClassCode);
```

use:

```
let myClassCode = fs.readFileSync('./js/myClass.js', 'utf-8');
myClassCode = 'MyClass = (' + myClassCode+ ')';
eval(myClassCode);
```

This doesn't just parse the class in `myClass.js` but assigns it to the in scope varaiable `MyClass` that can then be used to call class functions.